# Expressions separated by commas in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

I have this excel formula:

```
=PMT(B13/12,$C$5,-B12,0,0)
```

What does this formula do exactly?

Comment: As you can see by the answers it was pretty easy to google this and find an answer.  I would suggest a preliminary search for an answer before posting a question [ask].

Comment: @Nirk Then I would suggest adding the part of the description that isn't clear.  That would show the effort that the OP took to investigate.

Comment: I wanted to know what excel does to a formula that is in the format of =X(a,b,c). Is it a*b*c or any other thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As described in the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pmt-HP005209215.aspx)

> Calculates the payment for a loan based on constant payments and a
>   constant interest rate.
>
> Syntax
>
> PMT(rate,nper,pv,fv,type)
>
> For a more complete description of the arguments in PMT, see the PV
>   function.
>
> Rate     is the interest rate for the loan.
>
> Nper     is the total number of payments for the loan.
>
> Pv     is the present value, or the total amount that a series of
>   future payments is worth now; also known as the principal.
>
> Fv     is the future value, or a cash balance you want to attain after
>   the last payment is made. If fv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0
>   (zero), that is, the future value of a loan is 0.
>
> Type     is the number 0 (zero) or 1 and indicates when payments are
>   due.

In context `=PMT(B13/12,$C$5,-B12,0,0)`

- `B13` is the annual interest rate (so the monthly rate is `B13/12`)
- `C5` is the number of months of payments
- `-B12` is the present value
- `0` is the future value
- Payments are calculated as if they are due at the end of the month

Comment: I gave you a +1 on this as I thought your explanation was quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you had tried Google or looked at the help that is built into Excel you would have found that it's a function to `Calculates the payment for a loan based on constant payments and a constant interest rate`. For reference you can look it up [here](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/pmt-HP005209215.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

From http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pmt-HP005209215.aspx:

> Calculates the payment for a loan based on constant payments and a
>   constant interest rate.
>
> Syntax
>
> PMT(rate,nper,pv,fv,type)
>
> For a more complete description of the arguments in PMT, see the PV
>   function.
>
> Rate     is the interest rate for the loan.
>
> Nper     is the total number of payments for the loan.
>
> Pv     is the present value, or the total amount that a series of
>   future payments is worth now; also known as the principal.
>
> Fv     is the future value, or a cash balance you want to attain after
>   the last payment is made. If fv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0
>   (zero), that is, the future value of a loan is 0.
>
> Type     is the number 0 (zero) or 1 and indicates when payments are
>   due.